# Remove Task Pane info on saving document

Tags: javascript, office-js

I am trying to load excel document stored by means of office-js task pane app. We have a save document button in the task pane app. When we try to save the document, it looks like task pane addin settings also getting stored along with the document. I don't want that to happen. What happens is - when the stored document is opened after save, the excel document is trying to open the task pane app automatically. I would like this to happen when someone does go to Excel Menu>Insert>My Addins> and click on the respective Add-in name but not automatically.

From the docs, I see some property being set or we can set using the following code. But what property I need to target to remove the default loading of the add-in after save.

```
Office.context.document.settings.set(<Doc_Property>, true);
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented in the article [Automatically open a task pane with a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document#best-practices). The property is `Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument`:

```
Office.context.document.settings.set("Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", true);
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
```

Comment: Marc, You are saying that "Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument" is the property being set implicitly when we try to save the document. Pls let me know.

Comment: There isn't a setting be set implicitly. Add-ins are installed _in_ the document itself. In some ways it is easier to think of them as "document extensions" rather than "office extensions". The documentation I linked to shows how to control if the taskpane is automatically reopened when loading the document or not.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I do use the ***Office.context.document.settings.set("Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", false);*** and word still opening the add-in panel .? how I can make it not open automatically?